# Garantir que um conjunto de funções funcionem corretamente

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

Olá, pessoal!
Estou com um problema me corroendo e acho que não conseguirei solucionar sozinho... É o seguinte: Tenho um form com um botão; Esse botão é responsável por vender um produto.

A venda é feita em 3 etapas: Dar baixa no estoque; Adicionar o dinheiro do produto ao caixa; Adicionar o nome do produto à lista de produtos comprados pelo cliente;

Ficaria mais ou menos assim genericamente:

```
Function DarBaixaNoEstoque()
    'código aqui'
End Function

Function AdicionarDinheiroAoCaixa()
    'código aqui'
End Function

Function AdicionarProdutoAoCliente()
    'código aqui'
End Function
```

Aí é onde está o problema, todas as funções vão armazenar os dados em um banco MySql e, preciso que todas deem certo para que a venda seja realizada com sucesso. Porém, imagine só se a internet cair bem na hora que o usuário estiver vendendo... Preciso de um meio de segurança para que todas funcionem, seria um problema muito grande se 1 ou 2 funções não funcionassem corretamente.

Que opções eu tenho?
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Como está sendo feito o acesso ao banco? Está usando algum ORM, como Entity Framework ou NHibernate? Pergunto pois acredito que uma solução para o seu caso é a utilização de um pattern chamado [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), que seria muito mais fácil de implementar com o uso de um ORM.

Comment: Não estou utilizando nenhum desses artifícios, apenas criei uma classe com essas funções... O acesso ao banco de dados é por código mesmo, nenhum ORM... na verdade o q eu postei é um exemplo, vou começar um projeto do zero e preciso reunir ideias para obter mais segurança e desempenho.

Vou estudar um pouco sobre o padrão que você me indicou. Grato!

Mas ainda gostaria de mais opiniões, diversos jeitos de fazer a mesma coisa... Quero aproveitar o máximo de informação possível ;)

Comment: Eu estava pensando em fazer as funções retornarem um boolean dizendo se conseguiram ou não passar os valores pro banco de dados... E então, caso alguma desse errado eu reverteria as outras... Mas acho que seria um método bem pedreiro, não acho que seja a melhor opção

Comment: Estou bolando aqui uma implementação da Unidade de Trabalho com MySql e VB.NET, quando terminar coloco aqui.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado MarcusVinicius!
Se não for abusar da sua boa vontade, poderia comentar o código para que eu entenda melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para garantir *atomicidade* (1), tens de usar [transacções SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

A sintaxe específica depende da plataforma SQL. Eis um exemplo em MySQL:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE Inventory SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE productId = 123;
UPDATE Stores SET cash = cash + 500 WHERE storeId = 456;
INSERT OwnedProducts(clientId, productId) values(789, 123);

-- todas as operações foram executadas com sucesso -> commit
COMMIT;
```

Se alguma das operações falhar, a transacção será cancelada automaticamente com um `ROLLBACK` quando o cliente disconectar.

(1) Isto garante que as 3 operações são indivisíveis. Ou funcionam todas, ou não funciona nenhuma.

Recursos:

- [Transactions and Atomic Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)
- [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal! Vou estudar os métodos que foram usados como resposta, amanhã já começo com alguns testes ^_^

Comment: Consegui! Aqui fica a dica para quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu: http://pastebin.com/uDhEuw3t

Answer (score 1):

A minha sugestão é a adoção do padrão **Unidade de Trabalho** ([Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)). A sua definição é basicamente:

> Mantém uma lista de objetos afetados por uma transação de objetos de negócio e coordena a escrita de mudanças e a resolução de problemas de concorrência.

Vou dar um exemplo simplificado de implementação desse padrão aqui, sei que ele é muito mais complexo e extenso, mas acho que isso atenderá suas necessidades. Estarei utilizando junto o padrão de repositório também, mas acredito que seja facilmente adaptável a outros padrões de acesso a dados como DAL.

Começamos definindo uma interface para a Unidade de Trabalho. Isso porque acessos a diferentes banco de dados ou diferentes formas de acesso a dados (ADO.Net direto ou ORM) iriam mudar a implementação concreta da Unidade de Tranalho.

```
Public Interface IUnidadeTrabalho
    Inherits IDisposable
    Sub Commit()

    Sub Rollback()

    Function CreateCommand() As IDbCommand
End Interface
```

Então, para instanciar a Unidade de Trabalho, utilizamos um Factory, no qual já definimos a conexão e a deixamos pronta para uso.

```
Public Class UnidadeTrabalhoFactory
    Public Shared Function Criar() As IUnidadeTrabalho
        Dim conexao As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("MinhaConexao")
        conexao.Open()

        Return New UnidadeTrabalhoAdo(conexao, True)
    End Function
End Class
```

E aqui a implementação concreta da Unidade de Trabalho, utilizando ADO.Net. Sua função é bem simples: Recebe a conexão por parâmetro e abre uma transação. A partir daí, o controle do que vai ou não ser executado no banco de dados depende dela, com as ações `Commit` ou `Rollback`. Ela também é responsável por retornar o `DbCommand` que será executado no banco, que já estará ligado à transação aberta:

```
Public Class UnidadeTrabalhoAdo
    Implements IUnidadeTrabalho

    Private _conexao As IDbConnection
    Private _transacao As IDbTransaction

    Public Sub New(ByRef conexao As IDbConnection)
        Me._conexao = conexao
        Me._transacao = conexao.BeginTransaction()
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateCommand() As IDbCommand Implements IUnidadeTrabalho.CreateCommand
        Dim command As IDbCommand = _conexao.CreateCommand()
        command.Transaction = _transacao

        Return command
    End Function

    Public Sub Commit() Implements IUnidadeTrabalho.Commit
        If (IsNothing(_transacao)) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Não há transação aberta.")
        End If

        _transacao.Commit()
        _transacao = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Sub Rollback() Implements IUnidadeTrabalho.Rollback
        If (IsNothing(_transacao)) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Não há transação aberta.")
        End If

        _transacao.Rollback()
        _transacao = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If (Not IsNothing(_transacao)) Then
            _transacao.Dispose()
            _transacao = Nothing
        End If

        If (Not IsNothing(_conexao)) Then
            Me._conexao.Close()
            Me._conexao = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Aqui estou sugerindo a implementação de repositório para o seu negócio. A unidade de trabalho é injetada via construtor e o comando do banco deve ser feito a partir dela.

```
Public Class EstoqueRepositorio
    Private _unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho

    Public Sub New(ByRef unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho)
        Me._unidadeTrabalho = unidadeTrabalho
    End Sub

    Function DarBaixaNoEstoque()
        Dim command As IDbCommand = Me._unidadeTrabalho.CreateCommand()
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ..."

        REM código aqui
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CaixaRepositorio
    Private _unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho

    Public Sub New(ByRef unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho)
        Me._unidadeTrabalho = unidadeTrabalho
    End Sub

    Function AdicionarDinheiroAoCaixa()
        REM código aqui
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ClienteRepositorio
    Private _unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho

    Public Sub New(ByRef unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho)
        Me._unidadeTrabalho = unidadeTrabalho
    End Sub

    Function AdicionarProdutoAoCliente()
        REM código aqui
    End Function
End Class
```

E aqui finalmente onde tudo acontece de verdade. Quando chamar a ação de vender, uma nova instância da Unidade de Trabalho deve ser criada e injetada em cada um dos repositórios. Enquanto o método `Commit` da Unidade de Trabalho não for chamado, nada irá ser enviado ao banco. Caso haja algum erro, o bloco `Catch` será o lugar para fazer o `Rollback`. Por fim, deve ser chamado o `Dispose` para liberar a conexão.

```
Public Sub Vender()
    Dim unidadeTrabalho As IUnidadeTrabalho = UnidadeTrabalhoFactory.Criar()

    Try
        Dim repositorioEstoque = New EstoqueRepositorio(unidadeTrabalho)
        Dim repositorioCaixa = New CaixaRepositorio(unidadeTrabalho)
        Dim repositorioCliente = New ClienteRepositorio(unidadeTrabalho)

        repositorioEstoque.DarBaixaNoEstoque()
        repositorioCaixa.AdicionarDinheiroAoCaixa()
        repositorioCliente.AdicionarProdutoAoCliente()

        unidadeTrabalho.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        unidadeTrabalho.Rollback()
    Finally
        unidadeTrabalho.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```